# aws cdk: serve swagger ui with api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, swagger, aws-cdk

I want to use AWS ApiGateway to serve a swagger-ui of an API from a lambda function using express. For this I want to use the endpoint `GET /docs`.
My Lambda function `swaggerUiLambdaHandler` looks like this:

```or-tag-here
import express from 'express';
import serverless from 'serverless-http';
import swaggerUI from 'swagger-ui-express';

const options = {
  swaggerOptions: {
    url: 'https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json',
  },
};

const app = express();
app.use('/v1/docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(undefined, options));

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

In the `cdk` stack of the api, I added the following 2 endpoints for serving the index.html and the .js/.css resources:

```or-tag-here
const docs = myApi.root.addResource('docs');
docs.addMethod('GET', new apigw.LambdaIntegration(swaggerUiLambdaHandler));
const docsProxy = docs.addResource('{proxy+}');
docsProxy.addMethod('GET', new apigw.LambdaIntegration(swaggerUiLambdaHandler));
```

However, calling the endpoint with the browser, all network requests succeed but I get a white canvas and the error

```or-tag-here
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Do you have any idea? I think it might be related to the `content-type` returned by api gateway, but I would appreciate some help.

Comment: So I *thought* I had this licked by using the following function config:

```
import { NodejsFunction } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs'
const swaggerLambda = new NodejsFunction(this, 'swagger', {
  // put whatever other function props you need here
  bundling: { 
    nodeModules: [ 'express', 'swagger-ui-express' ]
  }
})
``` 

But now I'm not so sure. If I get it sorted quickly, I'll post an answer, because at one time I *did* have it working...

Comment: sorry that looks like crap. I didn't want to post it as an answer b/c the solution I thought I had wasn't working for me.